# Can I get cookies value or session value inside the has_permission method of django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, setcookie, django-sessions, django-permissions

I am working on a project where i have to check the user whether they belong the company or not.i am already put check while login user.
how i can use company id inside the has_permission() method?

```
class IsCompanyEmployee(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You are unauthorized to perform any action on this company.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                #company_id = request.COOKIES["company_id"]
                             #or
                #company_id = request.session["company_id"]
                return request.user.companyemployee_set.filter(company__id=company_id).exists()
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: do you have sessionauthentication on DRF?

Comment: no i am using token based authentication

Comment: just give it a try. enable the sessionauthentication, and try storing the company on your request.session... let me know if that works, meanwhile I will research another approach.

Comment: another question, which company do you store on the login? is this a USER company, or any COMPANY?

Comment: i am giving the option to user to select a company while login. its any company

Comment: hey its working now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IsCompanyEmployee(permissions.BasePermission):

    message = 'You are unauthorized to perform any action on this company.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                if 'company_id' in request.session:
                    company_id = request.session.get('company_id')
                    return request.user.companyemployee_set.filter(company__id=company_id).exists()
                else:
                    return False
        else:
            return False
```